# python: Remove trailing 0's and decimal point from awk command

Tags: python, bash, awk

I need to remove the trailing zero's from an export:

the code is reading original tempFile i need column 2 and 6 which contains:

```
12|9781624311390|1|1|0|0.0000
13|9781406273687|1|1|0|99.0000
14|9781406273717|1|1|0|104.0000
15|9781406273700|1|1|0|63.0000
```

the awk command changes the form to comma separated and dumps column 2 and 6 into tempFile2 - and i need to remove the trailing zeros from column 6 so the end result looks like this:

```
9781624311390,0
9781406273687,99
9781406273717,104
9781406273700,63
```

i believe this should do the trick but have had no luck implementing it:

```
awk '{sub("\\.*0+$",""); print}'
```

Below is the code i need to adjust: $6 is the column to remove zero's

```
if not isError:
    print "Translating SQL output to tab delimited format"
    awkRunSuccess = os.system(
            "awk -F\"|\" '{print  $2 \"\\,\" $6}' %s > %s" %
            (tempFile, tempFile2)
    )
    if awkRunSuccess != 0: isError = True
```

Comment: Are you asking for a Python solution, an awk solution, or a bash solution?

Comment: an awk solution if possible to fit in with the current code?

Comment: @A.Lat, See my updated answer

Comment: awk solution: `awk '{sub(/\|/,","); sub(/\.0*$/,"");}1' < tempFile`

Comment: Running Awk from within Python is incredibly misdirected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gsub("\\.*0+$","",$2)` to do this, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> echo '9781624311390|0.0000
9781406273687|99.0000
9781406273717|104.0000
9781406273700|63.0000' | awk -F'|' '{gsub("\\.*0+$","",$2);print $1","$2}'

9781624311390,0
9781406273687,99
9781406273717,104
9781406273700,63
```

However, given you're already *within* Python (and it's no slouch when it comes to regexes), you'd probably want to use it natively rather than start up an `awk` process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `awk` command

```
awk -F '[|.]'  '{print $2","$(NF-1)}' FileName
```

**Output:**

```
9781624311390,0
9781406273687,99
9781406273717,104
9781406273700,63
```